# Static Blocks in Java - Best Practices

Tags: java, static, ibatis

I have below static block in my java program and the same piece of code needs to be placed in several java files. Is there any best practice that exists to avoid copying & pasting this below piece of code in multiple files?

```
static Reader reader;
static SqlMapClient smc;


static {

    try {

        if(reader==null){
        reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("sqlmapconfig.xml");
        smc = SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(reader);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Move those codes to a separate Java class. Make the fields `public`, and you can access the fields on class name.

Comment: statics like this are evil and hard to test. Why not use singletons instead.

Comment: Agreed, it sounds like they shouldn't be static.  I would have a class which holds these two fields and this class could be in all the places you use this code now.

Comment: @LanceJava Singletons are evil too, for the same reasons ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey not if you let an IOC container manage them (eg spring)

Comment: @LanceJava IMHO That is not really a singleton, it is just an object you happen to create once.

Comment: @PeterLawrey po-tay-toe po-ta-to ;)

Comment: @LanceJava LOL, what's that?

Comment: @LanceJava Using an DI container is a better solution all round IMHO.  This allows you to create objects you might only need once, but importantly for unit testing you can create more if your need, or replacement easily.

Comment: @PeterLawrey you are preaching to the converted ;)

Comment: @RohitJain http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dskTypuEXoM

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class, where you write all static method in it. So you have a central palce to every static method.
For example:

```
public class AllMyMethod {

    public static myMethod() {

    try {
        if(reader==null){
            reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("sqlmapconfig.xml");
            smc = SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(reader);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static myMethod2() {

    }

.......

}
```

And then you do: `AllMyMethod.myMethod();`

For example, you can do the same thing with `static` and `final` variable...

Answer (score 1):

If you seriously want the "best practice", it is to use an IOC container to inject this stuff for you. The IOC container can read the configuration file and create the SqlMapClient for you and inject it into your DAOs.

There used to be a project called Ibatis-DAO that handled this kind of thing, when Clinton Begin deprecated it he specifically advised people to use Spring instead.